# How to create a function to extract field in string inside of vector?

Tags: c++

i want to make a function like this.

```
using namespace std;

vector<string> hj;

vector<string> feldseperator(const string& s, char delimiter) {

    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
    {
        token = s.substr(0, pos);
        cout << token << endl;
        hj.push_back(token);
        s.erase(); // I WANT TO DELETE THE FIRST FIELD + CHAR
    }
    return hj;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "dog;cat;fish;fax;fox;fast;";
    char f = ';';
    feldseperator(s, f);

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show? What are you really trying to do? What is the problem you try to solve? Please refresh how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You can't erase from `s`, as you made it `const`. Be aware that `find()` takes an optional second parameter - the position to start searching from. See if you can make use of that.

Comment: Repeating yourself does not clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see, you're trying to break string on basis of delimiters. Your problem is you want to remove prefix of string uptil first occurrence of delimiter - as stated by comment in your code. So, you could:

1. Use second param of [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/), which is "Position of the first character in the string to be considered in the search" and update your code like this:

   ```
   size_t last_pos = 0 , pos = 0;
   while ((pos = s.find(delimiter , last_pos)) != string::npos)
   {
    token = s.substr(last_pos,  pos - last_pos);
    last_pos = pos + 1; //pos is position of delimiter, you want next search to begin from character which comes after delimiter.
    ..
   ```

   }
2. Since you already have position of delimiter, you can reinitialize string s as `s = s.substr(pos+1 , s.size() - pos )` but then you'd have to removes const keyword, making option 1 a better choice.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this is not working . output :  dog_
cat;fis_
fish;fax;fox_    
fax;fox;fast; _   
fox;fast;    _
fast;

Comment: the output should be like dog "new line" cat "newline" fish...

Comment: @cain Please check now.

Comment: Great that did the work thank you i have seen that it starts from position 4 to 7 which means it takes cat;fis that was the problem . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

According to [std::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) (overload 3), it deletes in the range `[first, last)` hence the `+1`.

```
using namespace std;

vector<string> hj;

vector<string> feldseperator(const string& s, char delimiter) {

    auto copy = s;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    while ((pos = copy.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
    {
        token = s.substr(0, pos);
        cout << token << endl;
        hj.push_back(token);
        copy.erase(copy.begin(), copy.begin()+pos+1); // I WANT TO DELETE THE FIRST FIELD + CHAR
    }
    return hj;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "dog;cat;fish;fax;fox;fast;";
    char f = ';';
    feldseperator(s, f);

    cin.get();
}
```

Note that I'm passing a copy of the string, and not a reference. You may want to change that as required.

Comment: You should fully explain the answer instead of just dumping code

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Thanks for the input. I just added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks but this will only work if string s is not const i want it to be const

Comment: If the string is not too long you can make a copy.

Comment: @cain See my answer.

Comment: @cain, I just changed it to make a copy. But, E.N.D is doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understand, you want to split a string that contains substrings, delimited by a ";". This process is called tokenizing. Becuase you want to split a string into smaller tokens.

Modern C++ has a build in functionaliyt which is exactly designed for that purpose. It is called `std::sregex_token_iterator`. What is this thing?

As it name says, it is an iterator. It will iterate over a string (hence the 's' in its name) and return the split up tokens. The tokens will be matched again a regular expression. Or, nagtively, the delimiter will be matched and the rest will be seen as token and returned. This will be controlled via the last flag in its constructor.

Let's have a look at this constructor:

```
 hj(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
```

The first parameter is, where it should start in the source string, the 2nd parameter is the end position, up to which the iterator should work. The lase parameter is:

- 1, if you want to have a positive match for the regex
- -1, will return everything that not matches the regex

And last but not least the regex itself. Please read in the net abot regex'es. There are tons of pages available.

So, then we check the one liner for the field extraction.

```
std::vector<std::string> hj(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
```

What is that. The first is obvious. We define a `std::vector<std::string>>` with the name "hj". As possible with any variable definition, we will call a constructor, to construct the `std::vector<std::string>>`.

If you look in [std::vector range constructor (no 5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), you will see that we can initialize the vector, with a other iterator (begin and end), and copy the values from there. The begin iterator is given and the end iterator is given automatically with {}, because the empty constructor for the `std::sregex_token_iterator` is equal to its "end()".

That's it, everything done with a one-liner.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    // The string to split
    std::string s("dog;cat;fish;fax;fox;fast;");

    // The delimiter
    std::regex delimiter(";");

    // Tokenize and store result in vector
    std::vector<std::string> hj(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), delimiter, -1), {});

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Byt the way, if you have an existing vector, then you can copy the result into that vector:

```
std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(hj));
```

I hope that you can see the simplicity of that approach.

Of course there are many other possible solutions, and everybdoy can select whatever he wants.